# PHP: update through array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, sql-update, prepared-statement

I have a problem with the following code.

index.php

```
$table  = 'test';
$data = [
    'gerecht' => 'Spaghettie',
    'omschrijving' => 'Spaghettie van het huis!'
];
$id = '3';
$crud->updateData($table,$data,$id);
```

crud.class.php

```
    public function updateData($table,$data,$id){
    //Query opbouwen
    $query = "UPDATE {$table} SET "; 

    $last_key = end(array_keys($data));
    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $query .= $key ."=:". $key;
        if ($key == $last_key) {
            $query .= " ";
        } else {
            $query .= ", ";
        }
    }

    $query .= "WHERE id=:id";
    //Query opgebouwd

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);

    foreach($data as $key => $value){
        $stmt->bindparam(":". $key,$value);
    }

    $stmt->bindparam(":id",$id);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($stmt->rowCount()){
        return true; 
    } 
return false;
}
```

The code "works" but it doesnt do it the right way.
It does update at the requested id in the correct table, but the values are both the same.

The data base contains 2 cols (gerecht and omschrijving) and the values that will be updated to the database a both the values "omschrijving"

So whatever i put in gerecht wil be overwriten bij the value omschrijving .

Is there also maybe a more simple way for this code to work ?

Best regards 
Jocem

Comment: I tested it with the dollowing code

`<?php
$data = [
    'gerecht' => 'Spaghettie',
    'omschrijving' => 'Spaghettie van het huis!'
];
$table = "test";
$id = "3";
////////////////////////////////////


$query = "UPDATE {$table} SET "; 

$last_key = end(array_keys($data));
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
    $query .= $key ."=:". $key;
    if ($key == $last_key) {
        $query .= " ";
    } else {
        $query .= ", ";
    }
}

$query .= "WHERE id=:id </br>";
//Query opgebouwd

foreach($data as $key => $value){
   print "stmt->bindparam(:$key,$value)</br>";
}

?>`

Comment: you have `$query .= "$key = :$key";`

Comment: just print your `$query` after build and take a look to it

Comment: Correct cause the query should be ' UPDATE test SET gerecht=:gerecht, omschrijving=:omschrijving WHERE id=:id  '

Comment: I once has used this method to dynamically to set up query, but I found it is too restrict and lack of flexibility and go for hard code :(

Comment: I'm Dutch (the OP contains Dutch language), and for your interest: it's spelled `Spaghetti`, and not `Spaghettie`. I'm aware this has nothing to do with code, (unless you consider you're using spaghetti-code - just kidding).

Comment: @DaanHeskes, this code is better than 70-90% php written code :(

Comment: @vp_arth Yep surely! I was just kidding I only had some meme's come to my mind... I guess it's friday :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try followed:

```
  public function updateData($table,$data,$id){
    $set = [];

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        $set[] = "$key = :$key";
    }
    $set = implode(', ', $set);
    $query = "UPDATE $table SET $set WHERE id=:id";
    //Query opgebouwd

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);

    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        $stmt->bindparam(":$key", $data[$key]);
    }

    $stmt->bindparam(":id", $id);
    $stmt->execute();

    return (bool) $stmt->rowCount();
  }
```

I think, that issue can be with `$value` variable binding, this code binds placeholders to array members.

Comment: Well you sir , are my hero ;)
That did the trick indeed!
Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with comma seperated strings i suggest the function `implode` as this function will take care of not filling `,` at the end of your array so you don't have to.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Example

```
$table = 'test';
$data = [
    'gerecht' => 'Spaghettie',
    'omschrijving' => 'Spaghettie van het huis!',
];

$updateString = implode(',', array_map(function ($key){
    return sprintf("%s = :%s", $key, $key);
}, array_keys($data)));

$sqlString = sprintf('UPDATE %s SET %s WHERE id = :id', $table, $updateString);

$stmt = $this->db->prepare($sqlString);

array_map(function ($key) use ($data, $stmt) {
    $stmt->bindparam(sprintf(':%s', $key), $data[$key]);
}, array_keys($data));

...bind id, execute whatever
```

Comment: why you use `sprintf` for `set clause`, but not for table?

Comment: whoops my bad :) i will change it, ty

Comment: now looks ok) Main issue(reuse of loop temp variable) was fixed here too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly smaller version of your code:

```
public function updateData($table,$data,$id) {

    $query = "UPDATE $table SET "
    . implode( ', ',
      array_map( function($key) { return "$key=?"; }, array_keys( $data ) )
    )
    . " WHERE id=?";

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute( array_merge( array_values( $data ), [$id] ) );

    return $stmt->rowCount() != 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) foreach uses a different pointer 2) `$last_key = end(array_keys($data));` should throw OP a strict standard notice